# bizarre problem in visual studio code with renaming a file (F2) - goes out of edit mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I highlight a file and hit F2, the file is normally replaced with an edit box where you can rename it.

After a few seconds, the edit box goes away and you need to quickly type the different file name (every time).  I'm not sure what could cause this - any idea?

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Visual Studio code 1.52.1
Thanks

Comment: Maybe a linux issue, the rename input box never goes away for me except on focus elsewhere or Enter - I'm on W10.  I don't think there is any setting that is related.

Comment: Tried on my other ubuntu laptop- nothing happens there.  Personal laptop and different project and setup isn't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug reported in a few issues since v1.52 that all point to this one:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111652

also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112555 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112438

It is reported in 111652 as fixed in the Insiders' Build.  Can you test it there?  I can't reproduce in Stable Build, W10.

Comment: That looks very promising! I tried downloading the insiders build download is getting blocked so I can't test it.  I will keep an eye on that and try to get past it.